# Using jQuery with toggle events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html

I'm using some jQuery UI for a div that toggles on and off the screen.  On document load the div object is on the screen.  It works great but I was wondering if there was a way to set it so that it is hidden on document load, then the user would have the ability to click a button to make it appear.

I tried having the function run on `document.ready`, but that didn't seem to work.  Here is the code directly from the jQueryUI.

```
$(function() {
        // run the currently selected effect
        function runEffect() {
            // get effect type from 
            var selectedEffect = "slide";

            // most effect types need no options passed by default
            var options = {};
            // some effects have required parameters
            if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
                options = { percent: 0 };
            } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
                options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
            }

            // run the effect
            $( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
        };

        // set effect from select menu value
        $( "#button" ).click(function() {
            runEffect();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$("#button").hide()` should work, unless I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your CSS. This will set it to hidden by default.

```
#effect{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: :) don't be too harsh on yourself.

Comment: LOL, he's right. Everyone makes mistakes, no matter how simple they seem. :P

Answer (score 1):

the CSS solution above is the right way, but if you feel like doing it with javascript...

```
$(function() {
    $("#effect").hide();
});
```